# Can I rename my User folder name?

Tags: windows, windows-8, user-profiles

My logon name is `royin` and hence , I have an appropriate folder in :

[image]

Can I rename this folder to something else ? *( of course - not just rename , but letting the system know that from now on this is the folder).*

Related info :
*The **real** scenario is that I bought a computer with a user named "Admin" and they installed all the soft under this user. and so , I want to change it to `royin`.*

Comment: @Oliver Salzburg♦  , my question doesnt talk about microsoft account  whereas your solution does answer to a question which is regarding microsoft account .

Comment: My answer isn't the only one in that question. Either way, does the described process not work for you?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I don't want to take any chances on my machine. and I don't think that Microsoft account is like a regular user profile account.and that's why I think its not a dup. (my opinion :-)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg also , the other answer on other question is regarding _Windows XP/Vista_. (he actually bolds it). and besides , the question itself is **tagged** as Microsoft account.  so its definitely not a dup. ( IMHO).

Answer (score -1):

This Link should help you to change it I think.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-security/need-to-change-administrator-account-name-under/5def9249-1855-4c39-9acf-e9949b3ffbda

Comment: This is for windows vista.

Comment: At the moment, this post is essentially only a link. To make sure the answer remains useful even if the link breaks, please edit it to include the relevant information. (Your answer was discovered in [an effort to repair or remove old link-only answers](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11113/380318).)