# Can't install software? How do I change my C Drive username?

Tags: windows-10

I have a "!" as part of my username.

e.g.

```
C:\Users\name!>
```

Due to that, I encounter several directory issues installing some software including miniconda, apm for atom editor, etc.

Is there a way I could change my username safely and not affect/have minimal effect to the existing folders I have. Thanks!

Comment: Which Edition of Windows 10 are you using: Home, Pro (I assume it's not Enterprise or LTSB/C)? This makes a significant difference.

Comment: It would likely be easiest and best to simply create a new profile and migrate the data from `C:\Users\badName!` to `C:\Users\newUser` . Changing the profile name is _possible_ sure, but you will probably encounter issues that will take more time to correct vs. simply creating a new profile.

Comment: I am using Windows Home. Sorry, I wasn't aware that it will make a difference.

Comment: No worries. Are you using a Microsoft account or a local account?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename the User folder in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10)

Comment: [How to change username & user folder on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/q/1355431/241386), [Rename profile folder on Windows 7/8](https://superuser.com/q/570601/241386), [Can I rename my User folder name?](https://superuser.com/q/590479/241386)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say which version of Windows you were using.

However looks like its stored in the registry under:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`

try the advice here: https://winaero.com/blog/rename-user-profile-folder-windows-10/

Comment: I am using Windows Home Edition.

Comment: Apologies, missed the window-10 tag.  Did the advice in the link work?